# Pause page execution until after jQuery alert is closed, then run function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery `$.alert` and a `.fadeOut(1000)` working consecutively, but I dont like the result that I am seeing.  I would like to only run the `.fadeOut(1000)` after the user has closed the `$.alert`.  I know that you can't actually capture the close event of an alert, but can someone suggest a workaround that might accomplish what I am looking for?

Here is the existing `ajax` call where I am trying to implement the changes:

```
$.ajax({
url: sURL + "utility/mymethod",
type: "POST",
data: {ClientNum: ClientNum},
dataType: 'json',
success: function(json) {       
if (typeof(json.ClientEmail) != "undefined" && json.ClientEmail !== null && json.ClientEmail !== "") {
    $.confirm("Please call . . . .",                
    function(){ 
        if (json.ClientEmail){
            send_email(json);
        }
    },              
    function(){
        $.msg("Password recovery information has NOT been sent.",
        {header:'Password Not Sent', live:10000});
        $('#ajaxShield').fadeOut(1000);
    })
} else {
    //THIS IS WHERE I WANT THE FADEOUT TO WAIT FOR THE ALERT
    $.alert("There is no email address.")
    $('#ajaxShield').fadeOut(1000);
}; 
}, 
error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){ alert('Problem, Status code:'+xhr.status+', Error:'+thrownError);} 
});
```

I would like my overlay to remain visible until the user acknowledges the alert message.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems to working just like that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/e96wn/).

Comment: @BackinaFlash  `$.alert` is a modal plugin , not a native `alert`

Comment: plugin should have event callbacks...post link to docs for plugin. Likely a `close` event you can hook into

Comment: What jQuery plugin are you getting `$.alert` from?  It does not appear to be part of standard jQuery.  There should be callbacks that you can pass in that will tell you when it's done.

Comment: I have edited the question to show more context.

Comment: context is helpful but haven't provided link to docs for the plugin that creates `$.alert`, `$.confirm` etc

Comment: here is the plugin documentation that I am using: http://revaxarts-themes.com/whitelabel/doc-dialog.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$.alert is not native JQuery so is probably a plugin operating asynchronously. A google search suggests though that it isn't one of the better known ones.

Simple test...

Change

```
$.alert("msg")
```

To

```
alert("msg")
```

Does that look like what you are after (alert works synchronously).

If that's more like what you're after, the next stage is to identify how your plugin works (if you want to continue using it)

Comment: I've used similar plugins and they definitely have event callbacks which is the ideal solution

Comment: thanks for the help.  i will investigate event callbacks for this particular plugin.